# Is $\clubsuit_{\omega_1}$ enough to get Suslin tree?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, trees

This is problem 15.3 in Arnie Miller's [problem list](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/problems.pdf):

(Juhasz) Suppose there exists $\langle A_{\alpha} : \alpha \in L \rangle$, where $L$ is the set of limit ordinals below $\omega_1$ and for each $\alpha \in L$, $A_{\alpha}$ is an unbounded subset of $\alpha$, satisfying: For every unbounded $A \subseteq \omega_1$, there exists $\alpha \in L$, $A_{\alpha} \subseteq A$. Must there exists a Suslin tree?

What is the current status of this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Terminological disaster: The guessing principle named "club" is not the same thing as club-guessing.

Comment: Fortunately, there is a friendly disambiguating ambulance in the vicinity: http://papers.assafrinot.com/the_search_for_diamonds.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is negative apparently. It is consistent relative to ZFC that all Aronszajn trees are
special and that the club principle holds:

http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/mildenberger/postings/paperspdf/988_2014_10_15no.pdf

Comment: The link is broken.